# GMail Contexual Gadget - Multiple pattern to match more than one condition

Tags: javascript, gmail, text-extraction, gmail-contextual-gadgets

i'm developing a simple GMail Contextual Gadget (for now if 2 conditions are met there is a simple "hello world" in the gmail page).
But i need to match a double condition, and not only one. Because of that, i can't use the precanned extractors (if i use two extractor in the manifest, using the precanned ones, they work on OR condition).

According to [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-apps-developer-blog/JWrEdxBMfvU) there is a way to match a double condition:

> Custom extractors allow developers to trigger their gadget when a series of conditions are met. For example, a developer could write an extractor that triggered a gadget only when “Hello world” appeared in the subject **and** “jo...@example.com” was the sender of the email. This allows developers to more finely tune their gadgets, and provide even more relevant contextual information.

This is exactly what i need, i need to match if the sender is "xxx@xx.com" **AND** the subject is "zzz".

The problem is that i can't find any references about this problem in the [google api page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets#writing_a_custom_extractor)

How can i defined a *double AND condition* in a custom extractor?

Thanks
Bye

Comment: No sorry, i only used the subject as extractor

Answer (score 0):

Try using search pattern in custom extractor on one of your field and apply filter on other one in manifest.